# Show the Set of Polynomials without a constant term are dense in the Set of Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I'm looking to show that B = {the polynomials **without a constant term** (on compact space [a,b])} is dense in C = {all polynomials on [a,b]}

Is there a way to either shift the polynomials by a constant or to use closure of B to solve this?

Edit: 0 $\notin$ [a,b]

Comment: In order to define "dense" you do need to define a distance.in C (there are many of them).

Comment: If you use uniform convergence or pointwise convergence then you **need** $0 \not\in [a,b]$, it's not that $0$ doesn't need to be in $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: (need $0$ not in the domain) Take $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$, and approximate the function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ by a polynomial $P(x)$. Then $f(x)$ will be approximated by $x P(x)$.